# How to capture video from camera,process it (do some task on it),then show it real-time on the screen to the user in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to build a object detection android app,but how do I capture video from phone camera , detect objects from the video,and show it on the screen in real-time.I tried using the new CameraX PreviewView in Android,but it first shows the camera stream on the screen and only later gives us the option to do any processing on the video frames after the user has seen it.

Help would be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using Camera2 and ImageReader we are able to receive images from the camera.

Camera2 allows the users to register ImageReader's surface as a rendering target. This means, that the images are rendered to the ImageReader's queue and can be processed.

Once processed, You can draw the image on a TextureView's canvas, using drawBitmap method.

**Creating an ImageReader instance:**

```
this.imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(640, 480, ImageFormat.JPEG, 2)
imageReader?.setOnImageAvailableListener(
                onRawImageAvailableListener, cameraHandler)
```

**Opening the Camera**

```
val manager = getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
manager.openCamera("0", cameraStateCallback, cameraHandler)
```

**Registering the ImageReader's surface as a rendering target:**

```
val captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice?.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD) ?: return
val targets = listOf(imageReader?.surface)
targets.forEach { captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(it ?: return@forEach) }
cameraDevice?.createCaptureSession(
    targets, 
    object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        override fun onConfigured(cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession) {
            cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
                captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, cameraHandler)
            captureSession = cameraCaptureSession
         }
    
        override fun onConfigureFailed(cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to configure camera.")
        },
        cameraHandler
)
```

Receiving the images in ImageReader's OnImageAvailableListener:

```
private val onRawImageAvailableListener = OnImageAvailableListener { reader ->
        reader.acquireLatestImage()?.let { image ->
            handleImage(image)
        }
    }
```

A (very) basic Kotlin example I created is [here](https://github.com/gioravered/camera_image_reader)

Note that in order to create a smooth video you need to process your images on a different (not the camera's) thread, and to make sure your processing is done as efficiently as possible.

The example above is NOT efficient nor performance oriented - It is a basic program to understand the flow.